# python basic syntax boolean compare

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a question about the following code

```
 smaller={}
 for( dest in a[neigbour].keys())

    if(dest in smaller.keys() == False):
        print 'false'
    }
```

I can't make this code print `false`.. am I doing something wrong? I wonder if I am doing the correct thing to check the statement `dest in smaller.keys() == False`

Comment: You should never compare with `False` or `True` in conditional statements.

Comment: If you're testing membership in a dictionary, you don't need `x in d.keys()`, you can simply use `x in d`.  Similarly, `for x in d:` loops over the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oppisite of `dest in smaller.keys()` is `dest not in smaller.keys()`. No need to compare to `False` or `True`:

```
if (dest not in smaller.keys()):
```

Documentation for `in` and `not in`: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 4):

Your Python syntax is quite confused. For one, you need a `:` after your `for` statement, and it's generally not idiomatic to use braces around a `for` loop in Python. Also, instead of comparing to `False` with `==`, generally we use `not`:

```
smaller = {}
for dest in a[neighbour].keys():
    if dest not in smaller.keys():
        print('false')
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the other answers you've been given, the code could be written as:

```
for key in a[neighbour].viewkeys() - smaller.viewkeys():
    print key, 'not found'
```

Which takes advantage of the set like behaviour of `.viewkeys` to easily create a set of all keys in `a[neighbour]` not in `b`, then loops over that.